# Can't get correct localized language file from within added class (C# ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, cultureinfo, resourcemanager

C# ASP.NET

[image]

I have 3 files that contain different language strings (LocalizedText.resx, LocalizedText.de.resx and LocalizedText.en.resx).

I'm able to change the CultureInfo dynamically in my project and retrieve the correct language string with this code:

```
var lang = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = lang;
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = lang;


string str = LocalizedText.ResourceManager.GetString("getStringFromFile");
```

But if I use the same code within an added class in my project, it only gets strings from LocalizedText.resx. It doesn't matter what the CultureInfo is set to, it only retrieves from the LocalizedText.resx file.